# Как сохранить значение после обновления страницы

Tags: php, сессия

Есть вот такая вот кнопка "Включить / Выключить" звук.
Работает она хорошо,но если я нажимаю "Выключить звук" а затем обновляю страницу,звук снова включен и на кнопке опять написанно "Выключить звук".

Пожалуйста, помогите сделать так чтобы запоминалось значение.

```
<a class="music"> 
  <span class="text sound_on" style="display: none;">Включить звук</span> 
  <span class="text sound_off">Выключить звук</span>
</a>
```

Немного поясню как это работает: на моем сайте есть кнопочка "Выключить звук" при нажатии на нее, текст меняется на "Включить звук" но когда обновляю страницу все слетает и снова стоит "Выключить звук".

Comment: а при чем здесь php? достаточно просто при выключении/включении звука внести его состояние в куки, а при загрузке страницы выставлять вкл/выкл в соответствии с куками и проблема решена

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie
Имей в ввиду, что для использования cookie обязательно необходим веб сервер.

Comment: Я не смог разобраться в этом, не могли бы вы сделать правильно? Пожалуйста. И дать мне в готовом виде.

Comment: Я новичок в этом и многое не понимаю. Я пытался настроить код установки cookies но при входе на сайт показывает этот код....

Answer (score 1):

2 варианта, по сути похожих.

Пускай по умолчанию музыка выключена (0) или включена, не так важно.

1. **Серверный** с сессиями. Сохраняйте флаг музыка включена (1)/выключена (0) в сессию. При клике по sound_on/sound_off нужно посылать ajax-запрос на сервер, передавая в параметре 0 или 1, которые сервер положит в сессию `$_SESSION['music'] = $music`.

При обновлении страницы читайте значение из сессии

```
<?php $music = @$_SESSION['music']; ?>
<span class="text sound_on" style="<?=$music ? 'display: none;' : '';?>">Включить звук</span> 
<span class="text sound_off" style="<?=$music ? '' : 'display: none;';?>">Выключить звук</span>
```

2. **Клиентский** с куками без запроса на сервер. При клике по sound_on/sound_off ставьте куку (в данном случае пример с использованием `jquery.cookie.js`:

   $.cookie('sound', 1); 
   $.cookie('sound', 0);

При F5 проверяйте на js есть ли кука:

```
<a class="music">
    <span class="text sound_on">Включить звук</span>
    <span class="text sound_off">Выключить звук</span>
</a>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var sound = $.cookie('sound');
        if (sound_on) {
            $('.sound_on').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('.sound_off').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Я бы выбрал второй вариант. Если страница грузится медленно и заметно что кнопка исчезает когда `$(document).ready` срабатывает, вы можете на сервере получать значение куки `sound` и html на его основе показывать, как в первом варианте. Только вместо сессии проверять куку.

Comment: Не один из вариантов не работает :(

Answer (score 0):

Вот готовое решение для вашей задачи. Механика рабочая.
 Используйте связку Jquery + Jquery Cookie. В данном примере я использовал Jquery++.

Вот рабочая версия на fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wMN7G/362/

```js
$('#sound').change(function() {
  $.cookie('form', $('form').formParams(), {
    expires: 7 //дней
  });
});

$('#load').click(function() {
  $('form').formParams($.cookie('form'));
}).click();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
  padding: 20px;
}
p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 130px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://jquerypp.com/release/latest/jquerypp.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sound" id="sound" />
    <a class="on">Включить звук</a>
  </p>
</form>

<button id="load">Загрузить текущее значение</button>
```

Comment: Я пытался донести до вас механизм. Изменить могли бы и сами. Я поправил. Надеюсь поможет) Удачи) не забываем про благодарности.

Comment: Я вам очень благодарен но вы меня наверное не правильно поняли. У меня сайт venturefast.ru там наверху есть кнопка код которой я уже писал выше, так вот, я надимаю на нее и звук отключается а если нажимаю еще раз то он включается, но вот когда обновляю страницу, кнопка звука снова возвращается на стандартное значиение "Выключить звук". Мне нужно сделать чтобы если я нажал "Выключить звук" то при обновлении страницы было "Включить звук"

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно отключить звук именно у устройства - использование [локального хранилища](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) создано именно для этого, куки используются для устранения недостатков HTTP.
Если нужно отключать звук не у устройства, а у аккуанта (т. е. возможно с разных устройств), то проще запоминать состояние переключателя как свойство настроек пользователя и хранить на сервере, кука будет только для сессии.

Пример использования локального хранилища:

```js
let checkbox = document.querySelector('#sound');

// Сразу ставим переключатель в нужное положение
setSavedValue(checkbox);
// Отслеживаем переключение
checkbox.addEventListener('change', changeSound);

// Извлекаем/создаём состояние чекбокса (default: 1)
function setSavedValue(e){
  if(localStorage.getItem('soundState') === null){
    e.checked = true;
    localStorage.setItem('soundState', 1);
  }else{
    e.checked = localStorage.getItem('soundState') == 1;
  }
}

// Меняем состояние в хранилище, после перезагрузки страницы и даже удалении кук, это будет в сохранности
// Хотя и это очистить легко
function changeSound(e){
  // Ваш код, если нужно
  localStorage.setItem('soundState', localStorage.getItem('soundState') == 1 ? 0 : 1);
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='sound' />
```

P. S. Сниппет не сработает из-за ограничений фрейма, на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/axreL3wd/) он работает.